# How to register message mutators in a web application

Tags: ninject, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I'm using NServiceBus 4.0.3 with the Ninject builder and cannot figure out how to register message mutators (`IMutateTransportMessages`).

I've registered the mutator with the Ninject Kernel but it is never invoked. Below is how I'm configuring NServiceBus:

```
private static IBus ConfigureBus(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IMutateTransportMessages>().To<SendTenantIdMutator>();

    return NServiceBus.Configure.With()
        .NinjectBuilder(kernel)
        .XmlSerializer()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
        .UnicastBus()
            .LoadMessageHandlers()
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
}
```

Comment: Is there some special reason to register the mutator directly with Ninject as opposed to the regular NServiceBus container API: Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<SendTenantIdMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);

Comment: Could you tell me the version of NSB you are using? There where some internal changes in the latest release which interfere with the container. This helps me to provide a decent answer.

Comment: @UdiDahan does the container API still make use of Ninject internally?

Comment: Yes - calling .NinjectBuilder() routes all component registrations to Ninject behind the scenes.

Comment: @UdiDahan that worked thanks. Care to add an answer so I can mark it as so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some special reason to register the mutator directly with Ninject as opposed to the regular NServiceBus container API:

`Configure.Component<SendTenantIdMutator>(Dependency‌​Lifecycle.SingleInstance);`

I mean, this just calls internally into the configured container, which in your case would be Ninject.

Comment: or even `Configure.ConfigureComponent<SendTenantIdMutator>(Dependency‌​Lifecycle.SingleInstance);`

Comment: Right - forgot about the shorter form we created. Thanks Chris.